# Ramanujan's sum & Roots of Unity

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Ramanujan's sum is defined as: $$c_q(n)=\sum_{\substack{1\leq a\leq q \\\ (a,q)=1}}\exp\left(\frac{2 \pi ian}{q}\right)$$

Let $\eta_q(n)$ denote the sum of the nth powers of the qth roots of unity: $$\eta_q(n)=\sum_{1\leq a\leq q}\exp\left(\frac{2 \pi ian}{q}\right)$$

Why is it the case that: $\eta_q(n)=\sum_{d\mid q}c_q(n)$? In particular, we know:
$$\sum_{d\mid q}c_d(n)=\sum_{d\mid q}\sum_{\substack{1\leq a\leq d \\\ (a,d)=1}}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ian}{d}\right)$$

but I don't see how this guarantees we sum over all the $q$-th roots of unity $1\leq a\leq q$ especially when the inner sum is over the nth powers of the primitive roots of unity. Please be explicit in your justification.

Comment: Every $n$th root of unity is a primitive $d$th root of unity for a unique divisor $d\mid n$.

Comment: If we generalize the problem to $$\sum_{1\le a\le q} f\biggl(\frac aq\biggr) = \sum_{d\mid q} \sum_{\substack{1\le a\le d \\ (a,d)=1}} f\biggl(\frac ad\biggr)$$ for *any* function $f(x)$, can you see why the identity is true?

Comment: @GregMartin, your generalization helped me to gain an intuitive grasp of why this identity is true. Abstracting away from the particular clutter of the exponential allows me to better see what is happening. However, I'm still unsure why this identity holds in general and how the RHS is able to account for all the terms on the LHS.

Comment: @JohnSmith Try a concrete example (this is always a good idea for gaining intuition). Work out both sides exactly when $q=12$ for instance.